# How to specify that return value can either be str or None in the hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting

For the below code, PyCharm displays `'Expected 'Tuple[str, str]', got 'Tuple[None, None]' instead.`

```
def process(self) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    error_message = None
    report_type = None
    report_type_set = set()
    if not self.config_form.cleaned_data['type_check']:
        return report_type, error_message
    else:
        report_type, error_message = self._get_valid_value(report_type_set)
        return report_type, error_message
```

The method doesn't always return None, as you can see in the `else` block [ the method `_get_valid_value` makes sure we return `str` values for `report_type` and `error_message`]. So, how do I overcome this warning?

Is there a way to specify that it can either be str or None in the hinting?

Comment: Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]] might be your friend. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Tuple[str, str]`, you are indicating that this method *always* returns a tuple of strings.

Instead you can use:
`def process(self) -> Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]]:`

or alternatively:
`def process(self) -> Tuple[Union[str, None], Union[str, None]]:`

Answer (score 2):

It displays the warning because you have explicitly specified that it is returning only `Tuple[str, str]`.

I would suggest you use `Union` to specify both the str and None cases, if you do not have other cases of data types returning:

```
def process(self) -> Tuple[Union[str, None], Union[str, None]]:
    error_message = None
    report_type = None
    report_type_set = set()
    if not self.config_form.cleaned_data['type_check']:
        return report_type, error_message
    else:
        report_type, error_message = self._get_valid_value(report_type_set)
        return report_type, error_message
```